# What is the difference of url and url_helper on codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I just ended the tutorial and all through it it loads _url_helper_ as `$this->load->helper('url_helper');`. But then looking further on documentation I found `$this->load->helper('url');` Is there a difference between these two or `url` as a short for `url_helper`?

Comment: url is short of url_helper, if you call url_helper in helper method it will call url_helper_helper file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CI 3.x you can use both, as you'll find in the system core files: `/system/core/loader.php` around line 593 within `public function helper()`:

```
$filename = strtolower(preg_replace('#(_helper)?(\.php)?$#i', '', $filename)).'_helper';
```

as you can see `'url'` is translated into `'url_helper'` with above line

More about [CI URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#url-helper)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference between these two or url as a short for
>   url_helper?

`Answer :No difference`

Filename of a helper must end with `_helper` word.

You can load a helper with `full file name` or without `_helper` part